# Change BackColor of Disabled ComboBox and CheckBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I'm setting up a Windows Form application and i'm creating a read only version of a form and another version of the same form for adding/modifying information. In the read only version I am setting up the form so that all of the form components are read only. By default in Visual Studio 2008, when a form component is disabled, the BackColor property of that component is changed to a grey(ish) color. This can be simply rectified by setting the BackColor property of the component after it has been disabled; However this is not the case with a ComboBox or a CheckBox. Once these components are disabled I am unable to modify their colours. Does anyone know how to change the colour of these components after they have been disabled? I've tried the following code but to no avail.

```
comboBoxCategory.Enabled = false;
comboBoxCategory.BackColor = Color.White;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

For the check box, just handle the OnCheck event and undo it.

The simplest solution for the combo box is to only populate the one item.  Let the user drop-down if they click, but there will be nothing to change it to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can do this with these controls out of the box. You may have to extend the combobox and override the OnPaint() method.

You could also leave the combobox enabled, store the selected value (when changed to readonly mode) and use the SelectedIndexChanged event to maintain the selection.

I believe the same will need to be done for the checkbox, but use the CheckChanged event

Answer (score 0):

Change the BackColor of the ComboBox and CheckBox immediately after you have disabled them by code

Their is not event that will trigger on these controls when they get disabled or enabled

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were looking for:

```
    comboBoxCategory.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code I made it in VB it could help you solve your problem .
Put this code in your Form change comboBox1  to your control name ,
change the color to whatever you like     **.BackColor = Color.White**

```
Dim lbl_Box As Label
Private Sub Disable_control()

    If ComboBox1.Enabled = True Then
        lbl_Box = New Label
        With lbl_Box
            .Name = "lbl_Box"
            .BackColor = Color.White
            .Top = ComboBox1.Top + 1
            .Left = ComboBox1.Left
            .Width = ComboBox1.Width - 21
            .Text = ComboBox1.Text
            .Font = ComboBox1.Font
            .Padding = New Padding(0, 2, 0, 0)
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl_Box)
        ComboBox1.Enabled = False
        lbl_Box.BringToFront()
    Else
        lbl_Box.Dispose()
        Me.Controls.Remove(lbl_Box)
        ComboBox1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

*You can put the code with some changes in **ComboBox1_EnabledChanged** Event  rather then calling the procedure if you want.*